# Form Checkbox Group not sending all values to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, checkbox

When I have Checkbox code in my form and it is submitted to the Controller, only the FIRST checkbox value is sent and all other checked values are ignored.

Example chunk of form:

```
@:<input type="checkbox" name="commPref" value="23" />Home Phone
@:<input type="checkbox" name="commPref" value="24" />Cell Phone
@:<input type="checkbox" name="commPref" value="Work" />Work Phone
@:<input type="checkbox" name="commPref" value="26" />Email
@:<input type="checkbox" name="commPref" value="27" />Mail
```

After submission to Controller:

- if Cell Phone and Email are checked, "Model.commPref" = "24" -NOT-  "24,26"
- if Work Phone, Email, and Mail are checked, "Model.commPref" = "Work" -NOT- "Work,26,27"

I am completely baffled by this.  Does there need to be extra code around the form checkboxes to keep the values grouped together?  In ColdFusion, the form value that is sent back is a complete string of the values checked.  The 'name' of the form controls are all the same (commPref), so this should be the resulting value for this field.

**Edit**:  This is the Model description:

```
[StringLength(255)]
public string commPref { get; set; }
```

Comment: What is the type of property `commPref`? (it needs to be `IEnumerable<int>`)

Comment: Change the property to `public IEnumerable<string> commPref { get; set; }` (and remove the `[StringLength]` attribute. You posting back an array of values so the property needs to be an array

Comment: whats the input parameter of the controller action. try making it `string[] commPref`

Comment: After trying both suggestions, I get this error in both cases:  `The type 'string[]' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.StructuralTypeConfiguration<TStructuralType>.Property<T>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TStructuralType,T>>)'`  And it points me to this context snippet:  `modelBuilder.Entity<form_Data>()
                .Property(e => e.commPref);`

Comment: The error suggest that `commPref` is a property in a data model. In which case your going about this all wrong. You need a view model with property  `IEnumerable<string> commPref` because it needs to be an array to bind to the controls you creating. And then you can map to and from the view model using `String.Split()` and `String.Join()` assuming `commPref` in the data model is typeof `string` (and you want a (say) comma separated list)

Comment: You are absolutely correct @StephenMuecke. I was trying to add this to my data Model.  This is what I finally added to my View Model:  `[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult form(form_Data form_data, IEnumerable<string> commPref)`  I then added code to combine the array of strings in commPref into one string (again, like you suggested). .

Comment: I am trying to code a dynamic form creator, where I don't care ahead of time what form elements are in the form.  But MVC/EF has been fighting me all the way on this and it finally beat me with the Checkbox element.  I have to know ahead of time if Checkboxes are present and add the code in the Controller to handle them.  Bummer.  Thank you so much for your quick help!

Comment: As always, use view models (do not use data models in views when editing)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help of all the commenters on this post, here is what ended up fixing my situation:

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult form(form_Data form_data, IEnumerable<string> commPref)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) // Perform DB Actions
        {
            // Checkbox Object Loop - commPref field
            // Loop through each string array element of form field to build resulting field value
            if (form_data.commPref != null)
            {
                //Code to make comma-delimited list of Checkbox choices
                //form_data.commPref = string.Join(",", commPref);
                //Wraps each Checkbox choice in pipes (|) to strictly define choice for display on form
                form_data.commPref = "|";
                foreach (var item in commPref)
                {
                    form_data.commPref += item;
                    form_data.commPref += "|";
                }
            }

            if (form_data.dataID != 0) // Edit Record
            {
                db.Entry(form_data).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index", new { msg = 2 });
            }
            else // Create Record
            {
                db.formapp_Data.Add(form_data);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index", new { msg = 1 });
            }

        }
        else // Show Errors
        {
            var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This declaration also works in the ActionResult:  `[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult form(form_Data form_data, string[] commPref)`

Answer (score 0):

I know this must be insanely late but just incase anyone else finds themselves here..

MVC does have a way to handle checkbox groups.

in your view model:

[Display(Name = "Which Credit Cards are Accepted:")]

public string[] EmployeeRoles{ get; set; }

On your Page:

```
            <input id="EmployeeRoles" name="EmployeeRoles" type="checkbox" value="Supervisor" 
            @(Model.EmployeeRoles != null && Model.EmployeeRoles.Contains("Supervisor") ? "checked=true" : string.Empty)/>
            &nbsp;<span>Supervisor</span><br />

            <input id="EmployeeRoles" name="EmployeeRoles" type="checkbox" value="Auditor" 
            @(Model.EmployeeRoles != null && Model.EmployeeRoles.Contains("Auditor") ? "checked=true" : string.Empty)/>
            &nbsp;<span>Auditor</span><br />

            <input id="EmployeeRoles" name="EmployeeRoles" type="checkbox" value="Administrator" 
            @(Model.EmployeeRoles != null && Model.EmployeeRoles.Contains("Administrator") ? "checked=true" : string.Empty) />
            &nbsp;<span>Administrator</span>
```

I tried very hard to create these controls with razor but no dice. It keeps
creating that hidden field you all have referred to. for your checkbox group 
you don't need that hidden field, just the code I have added above.  You can create an html helper to create this code for you.

```
    public static HtmlString CheckboxGroup<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> propertySelector, Type EnumType)
    {
        var groupName = GetPropertyName(propertySelector);
        var modelValues = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(propertySelector, htmlHelper.ViewData).Model;//propertySelector.Compile().Invoke(htmlHelper.ViewData.Model);

        StringBuilder literal = new StringBuilder();  

        foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(EnumType))
        {
            var svalue = value.ToString();
            var builder = new TagBuilder("input");
            builder.GenerateId(groupName);
            builder.Attributes.Add("type", "checkbox");
            builder.Attributes.Add("name", groupName);
            builder.Attributes.Add("value", svalue);
            var contextValues = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.GetValues(groupName);
            if ((contextValues != null && contextValues.Contains(svalue)) || (modelValues != null && modelValues.ToString().Contains(svalue)))
            {
                builder.Attributes.Add("checked", null);
            }

            literal.Append(String.Format("</br>{1}&nbsp;<span>{0}</span>", svalue.Replace('_', ' '),builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal)));
        }

        return (HtmlString)htmlHelper.Raw(literal.ToString()); 
    }

    private static string GetPropertyName<T, TProperty>(Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> propertySelector)
    {
        var body = propertySelector.Body.ToString();
        var firstIndex = body.IndexOf('.') + 1;
        return body.Substring(firstIndex);
    }
```

on your page use it like so:
@Html.CheckboxGroup(m => m.EmployeeRoles, typeof(Enums.EmployeeRoles))

I use an enum but you can use any kind of collection